# Does the order of unhiding and loading a webview affect performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a loading view with a progress bar so the user can watch a PDF's download progress. When the download completes I unhide the webview and then call loadRequest. I was just wondering if there is any difference between:

> [self.webView setHidden:NO];
>
> [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:localURL]];

Versus

> [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:localURL]];
>
> [self.webView setHidden:NO];

I ask because I assumed loadRequest happens in its own queue, so I thought there couldn't be any visible differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they have differences between them.

Because ***loadRequest*** is asynchronous, it won't block the main thread.